# Como acessar um par de valores dentro de um DataFrame pandas/Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Olá, amigos, tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução que verifica se um par de valores numa lista corresponde a um par de valores DataFrame. Esse DataFrame é o relatório de municípios do IBGE (https://www.ibge.gov.br/explica/codigos-dos-municipios.php -> Tem uma área de download, onde está disponível um .xls dos dados).

Eu preciso que essa aplicação me devolva o seguinte:

- Dada uma determinada lista, conferir se um par UF/Município existe no DataFrame.

Ex.:

```py
Publicação = [livro, ano_publicacao, uf_lançamento, município_lançamento]
```

- Preciso confirmar se esse par UF/Município existe no DataFrame (Para evitar que Bonito/PA seja confundido com Bonito/BA, por exemplo, ou que Bonito/DF não seja retornado por que não existe).

Idealmente, eu preciso que essa função me retorne os valores UF/Município que foram encontrados e me retorne um booleano indicando se existe ou não o par.

Eu dei uma olhada na documentação do pandas, mas não encontrei uma função que faça isso (se existe, me passou despercebido).

A estrutura do DataFrame é a seguinte:

```
     Nome_UF  Código Município Completo           Nome_Município
0         RO                    1100015    Alta Floresta D'Oeste
1         RO                    1100379  Alto Alegre dos Parecis
2         RO                    1100403             Alto Paraíso
3         RO                    1100346         Alvorada D'Oeste
4         RO                    1100023                Ariquemes
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar à pergunta como é a estrutura do Dataframe com os municípios? Quais são as colunas?

Comment: Claro, é UF/Município!
Vou adicionar, obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar a função `isin()` do pandas para verificar se um valor existe em um DataFrame. No entanto, como você está procurando por um par de valores, você precisará combinar essa função com uma operação lógica. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Suponha que df seja o seu DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nome_UF': ['RO', 'RO', 'RO', 'RO', 'RO'],
    'Código Município Completo': [1100015, 1100379, 1100403, 1100346, 1100023],
    'Nome_Município': ['Alta Floresta D\'Oeste', 'Alto Alegre dos Parecis', 'Alto Paraíso', 'Alvorada D\'Oeste', 'Ariquemes']
})

def check_uf_municipio(df, uf, municipio):
    # Verifica se a UF e o Município existem no DataFrame
    uf_exists = df['Nome_UF'].isin([uf])
    municipio_exists = df['Nome_Município'].isin([municipio])

    # Retorna um DataFrame onde ambos a UF e o Município existem
    result = df[uf_exists & municipio_exists]

    # Se o DataFrame resultante não estiver vazio, então o par UF/Município existe
    exists = not result.empty

    return result, exists

# Testando a função
result, exists = check_uf_municipio(df, 'RO', 'Alta Floresta D\'Oeste')
print(result)
print('Existe:', exists)
```

Neste exemplo, a função `check_uf_municipio()` recebe o DataFrame, uma UF e um Município como argumentos. Ela verifica se a UF e o Município existem no DataFrame e retorna um novo DataFrame que contém apenas as linhas onde ambos existem. Ela também retorna um booleano que indica se o par UF/Município existe ou não.

Por favor, note que esta função assume que a UF e o Município são únicos no DataFrame. Se houver múltiplas linhas com a mesma UF e Município, todas serão retornadas.

Comment: Edif, sinto que esse é o caminho que preciso seguir. Ainda não consegui adaptar a sua lógica ao meu problema, que é maior do que o que eu apresentei, mas a sua solução está no caminho certo!
Farei novas atualizações quando eu conseguir resolver tudo.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Edif, eu consegui resolver completamente meu problema. Muito obrigado.
Precisei fazer algumas alterações, me preocupar com o "case sensitive" do Pandas/Python, e consegui validar as informações que eu precisava. A sua ajuda foi fundamental.